# Convert database null to DateTime.Empty

Tags: nhibernate, datetime

Are there any way I can configure nhibernate to set `DateTime.MinValue` instead of null when the database column contains null (and vice versa)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet it to use a custom implementation of IUserType, a interface which defines translation between a native type (DateTime) and a SQL type (datetime). The key pieces are the NullSafeSet/NullSafeGet methods, which define the transfer between IDbCommand/IDataReader and the object value in question.